# Why jquery function can not be executed for two images that have the same ID

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

i have the following script inside my asp.net MVC application to bounce the image

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#to-get-bigger").mouseover(function () {
            $(this).effect("bounce", { time: 3, distance: 40 });
        });
    });
```

and on the view i have the following two images with the same Id:-

```
<a href="@Url.Action("StartAssessment", "StartAssessment", new { assessmentid = Model.AssessmentID })" 
onclick = "return confirm('This will make the Assessment avilable for the regestred user.')" > 
   <img id = "to-get-bigger" border="0" src="@Url.Content("~/content/images/assessment-button1.jpg")" alt="start assessment" />
</a>

 <a href="@Url.Action("StartAssessment", "StartAssessment", new { assessmentid = Model.AssessmentID })" 
onclick = "return confirm('This will make the Assessment avilable for the regestred user.')" > 
   <img id = "to-get-bigger" border="0" src="@Url.Content("~/content/images/assessment-button1.jpg")" alt="start assessment" />
</a>
```

But the problem is that the Jquery function will only execute and bounce one image while it will not work on the second image,, although i have read that the Jquery selector in this case the `#to-get-bigger` will return all the elements that have this ID and the Jquery function will be executed once the user move the mouse on any of the intended elements ?
BR

Comment: I personally only use IDs for unique things, and classes for this kind of stuff which is more global over several objects.

Comment: How are IDs supposed to *identify* if they aren't unique?

Comment: An ID is unique, as per the name, therefor it is not valid to use the same ID for two elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having multiple elements with the same `id` is invalid, and causes issues like this. The `id` attribute should be unique. To reference multiple elements with a single attribute, use a `class`:

HTML

```
<a href="@Url.Action("StartAssessment", "StartAssessment", new { assessmentid = Model.AssessmentID })" onclick="return confirm('This will make the Assessment avilable for the regestred user.')" > 
    <img class="to-get-bigger" border="0" src="@Url.Content("~/content/images/assessment-button1.jpg")" alt="start assessment" />
</a>

<a href="@Url.Action("StartAssessment", "StartAssessment", new { assessmentid = Model.AssessmentID })" onclick="return confirm('This will make the Assessment avilable for the regestred user.')">
    <img class="to-get-bigger" border="0" src="@Url.Content("~/content/images/assessment-button1.jpg")" alt="start assessment" />
</a>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".to-get-bigger").mouseover(function () {
        $(this).effect("bounce", { time: 3, distance: 40 });
    });
});
```

Comment: but in my case what i am trying to achieve is that i have a view that display around 20 item images and i want incase the user move the mouse over any of these 20 images to bounce the associated image ,, so how i can achieve this requirment; should i for example provide 20 different IDs and same as for the jquery functions !!!

Comment: The example I gave does exactly that - every element which has the class `to-get-bigger` will run the code specified. You don't need to give each one it's own class and event handler.

Answer (score 3):

Id's must be unique. The native javascript method that jQuery uses `document.getElementById()` only returns the first element it finds with a specific ID.

If you select elements using jQuery by ID, it will only return one element since there can only be one valid element with that ID. There are some edge cases though where I have seen it work, such as with the jquery corners plugin, though even that doesn't work in all browsers when not using unique ID's.

Answer (score 1):

No, it will get an collection of one Id named #to-get-bigger, and ID must be uniqe on a page, you should use a css class instead. http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2 gives you the w3c spec on how it works.